# Why I can not transfer "context" from endpoint Django app to HTML page?

Tags: python, html, django, render

I've got the problem with transfering {context} from Django endpoint to HTML. I added to the project second application (first was "tasks" and everything work good, second is "notes" and the problem is with this one). I don't know why but information from *context* are not transfer to HTML.

Python: notes/views.py

---

```
@login_required(login_url='/user_login/')
def notes_list(request, *args, **kwargs):

if request.method == "POST":
    name = request.POST.get("name")
    description = request.POST.get("description")
    new_note = Notes.objects.create(
        name=name,
        description=description,
        user=request.user
        )
    new_note.save()
    return redirect("/notes_list/")

notes = Notes.objects.all().filter(user=request.user)
print("notes", notes)
context = {
    notes: "notes",
}
return render(request, 'notes_list.html', context)
```

---

HTML: templates/notes_list.html

---

```
List:
{%for note in notes%}
<b>Title:</b>
    <textarea  class="form-control" rows="1" cols="1"  name='name' >{{note.name}}</textarea>
<b>Note:</b>
    <textarea  class="form-control" rows="3" cols="1"  name='description' >{{note.description}}</textarea>
{%endfor%}
```

---

When I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/notes_list/ I see just "List:" and empty page (without notes list). Model db is correct - *print("notes", notes)* print all rows in console so there is everything OK.

This is settings.py file:

---

```
    TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
     },
   ]
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
context = {
    notes: "notes",
}
```

To

```
context = {
    "notes": notes,
}
```

---

*Also add space after `{%` and before `%}` in your `template`*